# How to compile a FORTRAN IV program with ifort?

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I need to compile a FORTRAN IV program. I found in the Internet that Intel FORTRAN compiler ifort supports also the FORTRAN IV version. I downloaded a 30 days trial version of Intel compiler. However when I try to compile the program simply by:

```
ifort  name.for
```

(where name.for is the name of the source file) I get too many errors, and it seems that ifort doesn't regard the file as a FORTRAN IV source file.

How should I run this FORTRAN IV program using ifort ?

Comment: Use the `-f66` compiler switch

Comment: Depending on the original program, this may work exactly right or not at all. If you still have trouble, edit your question to include the specific errors.

Answer (score 4):

You do not give much details about what you intent to do here, but here is the command line I would try:

```
ifort -f66 name.for -o mycode
```

This assumes that `name.for` is the only source file you want to compile. If not, you might want to try:

```
for f in *.for; do ifort -f66 -c $f; done; ifort -f66 *.o -o mycode
```

And finally, it might be the case that there are pre-processor directives into your Fortran sources. If so, you have 2 solutions:

1. Either renaming your sources from `name.for` to `name.FOR`;
2. Or adding `-fpp` to your compiler command line for forcing the call to the Fortran pre-processor.

Hope this helps.